# King, Queen and Magician. "Mad" and "sane"/"conscious magicians"

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm not sure about any of this.

Quite a long fantasy novel and probably written for children.  Might have been a new one or an old one.

The kingdom always had a King, a Queen and a Magician - or possibly it wasn't Queen, possibly it was King, Warrior and Magician, or something like that.  When the Magician died, or perhaps when he got old, a new Magician would take his place - possibly chosen by non-magical means or possibly chosen magically or even just appearing out of nowhere.

Usually, the Magicians were always mad (I don't remember in what way).  But it was suspected that if there was ever a "sane magician", also referred to as a "conscious magician", he'd be very powerful.

It may have been, though this idea only rings a very faint bell, that the Magician only went mad when he became the Magician, and that our hero was only a Magician-in-waiting at this point and had that hanging over him.

Any ideas?

Comment: Standard questions:  when did you read this?  Any idea what the cover looked like?  Paperback, hardcover, e-book, other?

Comment: If I knew, I'd have said.  I did say I didn't know whether it was a new or old one.  Don't think it was an e-book, though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Elements of this sound similar to Roger Zelazny's *[Chronicles of Amber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Amber)*, in particular *The Courts of Chaos*. If that is the case then the insane Magician would be Dworkin and the hero about to risk the same fate is his son Oberon and/or his warrior grandson Corwin. Dworkin is much more powerful when he regains his sanity and in the earlier books there is continual competition for the vacant throne among Oberon's warrior sons. But the rest of it doesn't seem to fit in particular because the Amberites are effectively immortal so there was no expectation of the Magician going anywhere and someone else inheriting his role. The king going missing was a major issue because he had nine acknowledged sons by four mothers and no designated heir among them when he disappeared.

Comment: Nope, doesn't fit.  But thanks!

Comment: @A.B. can you say what doesn't fit? That will help anyone else trying to find the book.

Comment: There is also no (single) Queen in the (1st) Amber chronicles. One of the points of strife between Oberon's children was that there were multiple mothers producing them.

Comment: This basically doesn't fit at all.